# How Symfony container collects vendor classes?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am working on very old legacy code, mostly procedural. Trying to improve it. Rewriting applications is impossible right now. The plan is to add a few libraries which would help organize things and improve that way.

I added a Symfony dependency-injection component in order to do that. It would provide the possibility to fetch needed services with its dependency easy.

I watched symfonycast tutorial on how to play with container. And with that knowledge, I managed to write a simple loader to start the container and to use services made by me. It is simple, it guesses FQCN based on file path, and then uses reflection to get dependencies. But I can not figure out how to load vendor classes, because here you can not guess namespace that way. :)

**The question is: What exactly Symfony uses to load classes from the vendor folder, does it reads composer.json files to see namespaces, does it uses some composer feature, or something else?**

Comment: Components/libraries/services can use [configuration files](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html#setting-up-the-container-with-configuration-files) and/or [bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html).

Comment: That said, having done something similar to what you are doing, I would personally recommend just manually registering the services you actually need, which really shouldn't be too many if you are just patching an existing application. It might also be easiest to create and register some [factories](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html) that instantiate some of your classes, too.

Comment: Actually, that is a very ok idea. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Loading* classes is different than *instancing services*.

The first can in fact use regular composer facilities to [discover vendored classes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) in a legacy project like yours, even if they weren't installed with composer. This uses the standard [php `autoload`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) mechanism with some added magic.

To include the, let's say `lib/` legacy directory in the discoverable files you would add the following to `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["lib/"]
}
```

And then run `composer dump-autoload`. Note that by including `vendor/autoload.php` in your legacy files you could even forego the `require` directives for your dependencies and rely on composer as well. This can be a path for migrating them to composer-managed dependencies, too.

Service instancing requires not only being able to locate the classes themselves, but also their respective dependencies so the container can create the object tree automatically. This *usually* involves hand-writing service definition files: classes in the `vendor/` folder are *not* automatically registered as services. A bundle (or your own definitions) enables support for an specific library.

Take for instance the [Mailer *component*](https://github.com/symfony/mailer): you can use it as a standalone library, but for framework integration (which includes service definitions and depen) you'd need to install Mailer *bundle* as well.

The exception where automatic service registration applies (when using symfony framework, not the standalone dependency injection component) is for files under `src/`. During container compilation, `services.yaml` is loaded and the [`ContainerConfigurator`](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/c1831682d0a02ee2ce07c06b3cdaeaf8d73075cf/Loader/Configurator/ContainerConfigurator.php#L61) with help from [`FileLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/c1831682d0a02ee2ce07c06b3cdaeaf8d73075cf/Loader/FileLoader.php#L172), looks for `*.php` files the directories configured as a `resource`, creating service definitions for them.

I guess you could do a similar thing for your legacy dependencies in a [`CompilerPass`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) by using a similar technique or by trying to leverage the composer classmap but, specially if your legacy dependencies do not follow a PSR loading standard, I'd advise against it, since it can pull in tests, example files, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not answer the question. And cast you have mentioned is the same i said I watched in the question. Load classes i definitely not instancing services but before instancing symfony must get their metadata. And that's what the question is about, how symfony does it for vendor classes.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding, it is not point in composer loading that is ok, it happens in index.php as you say but to load classes to container symfony must read those classes to create definitions and references to get metadata by reflection. That must be like that for classes in src/ but vendor classes are different because your app can not gues namespaces so there is few posibilities: 1 container reads from composer.json of each package, it uses autoload_classmap.php from composer or does not load all vendor at all but uses what is neede at the moment.

Comment: Please @msg edit your answer to contain this last comment so I can accept it, that is answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @some_guy I've cleaned up the comments and incorporated them into the answer, fixing a minor mistake and changing things a bit. I've also added the last paragraph for a possible way forward (although I'd discourage it). Let me know if something is unclear or feel free to edit it yourself.